# How to delay AppLoading in React Native? Some elements load faster than others?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

Im developing a React Native app in Expo and I have a custom splash screen animation that I have up initially after the `AppLoading` splash screen disappears. This works in simulator - the animate out transition is an `Animated.timing` moving from 1 to 0.

Problem is, on an actual iPhone, theres a split second where the AppLoading disppears and the secondary animated splash screen (an `Animated.Image`) isn't behind it. Other elements of the app have loaded in that split second though.

This happens even if I take out the "animate out" animation. So my logic is to delay the AppLoading disappearing by 1 second long enough for the secondary splash to be steadily in place.

How can I do this? What is happening here?

**EDIT:** Only mention of AppLoading is here:

```
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
```

The animated splash screen elements

```
<Animated.Image pointerEvents={"none"} style={[styles.splash, { opacity: splashOpacity }]} source={require('./assets/splashnew.png')} />
    <Animated.Image pointerEvents={"none"} style={[styles.splashTxt, { opacity: splashOpacity, transform: [{scaleY: splashScale }, {scaleX: splashScale }]} ]} source={require('./assets/splash.png')} />
```

Are controlled by this function:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.delay(1000),
      Animated.spring(splashScale, {
        toValue: 1,
        bounciness: 4,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        speed: 2
      })
    ]).start()

    const interval = setInterval(() => {

      Animated.sequence([

          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.spring(splashScale, {
              toValue: 0,
              bounciness: 4,
              useNativeDriver: false,
              speed: 2
            }),
            Animated.spring(splashOpacity, {
              toValue: 0,
              bounciness: 2,
              useNativeDriver: false,
              speed: 3
            }),
```

Comment: can you show your App.js code? that typically contains the code to hide the app loading splash page.

Comment: @WenW check my edit

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is setup another state variable and use that instead of fontsLoaded.

```
   const [waitOneSecond, setWaitOneSecond] = useState(false);

   useEffect(()=>{
     if (fontsLoaded) setTimeOut(()=>{setWaitOneSecond(true);},1000);
   },[fontsLoaded]);


  if (!waitOneSecond) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
```